# How to draw a heatmap in R using heatmap.3 package

Tags: r, heatmap

I've seen a few sources to draw a heatmap in R using the standard `heatmap` and `heatmap.2` packages, but I have yet to come across an example using the new `heatmap.3` package.  The only source I could find for this was https://www.biostars.org/p/18211/.  However, even here, the author makes his own `heatmap.3` package, not the standard `heatmap.3` package from CRAN http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GMD/GMD.pdf.  I tried figuring out how to make a heatmap with `heatmap.3` from that CRAN documentation, but I didn't even know where to start.  I immediately got lost in all the 50+ options.  Can anyone get me started?

My tab-delimited input file looks like this:

```
EntryA  EntryB  EntryC  EntryD  EntryE
John    48  31  57  55
Mary    88  11  89  78
Sarah   33  66  42  54
```

Answer (score 1):

See below a basic example using heatmap 3 on your data (for a nicer plot, axes etc need to be edited). The critical step is to create a matrix with rownames. I turned the data.frame to a matrix as this is done in the examples provided in the GMD manual but it also works fine on data.frames.

```
library(GMD)

dat<-data.frame(EntryA=as.numeric(c(48,88,33)), EntryB=as.numeric(c(31,11,66)), EntryC=as.numeric(c(57,89,42)), EntryD=as.numeric(c(55,78,54)))

rownames(dat)=c("John","Mary","Sarah") 

ndat<-as.matrix(dat)

heatmap.3(ndat, Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very much like `heatmap.2`.  Can you implement this `heatmap.3` command to demonstrate what advantage/improvement/modification it has over `heatmap.2`?  I've seen a plot almost identical produced just using `heatmap.2`.

Comment: Actually your original question was not to show what heatmap3 does better than heatmap2, your question was how to make a heatmap with heatmap3. As you said you got lost I kept things very basic and for that reason of course it looks very much like previous versions.